# ActiveMQ can't start broker on linux mint 16

Tags: java, activemq-classic

This is what I see in console output.

> Loading message broker from:
>   xbean:file:/home/michael/Code/apache-activemq-5.9.0/stomp.xml  INFO |
>   Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@4902f4c3:
>   startup date [Tue Dec 10 13:44:21 MSK 2013]; root of context hierarchy
>   ERROR | Failed to load: URL
>   [file:/home/michael/Code/apache-activemq-5.9.0/stomp.xml], reason:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in URL
>   [file:/home/michael/Code/apache-activemq-5.9.0/stomp.xml]: Invocation
>   of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/derby/jdbc/EmbeddedDataSource
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in URL
>   [file:/home/michael/Code/apache-activemq-5.9.0/stomp.xml]: Invocation
>   of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/derby/jdbc/EmbeddedDataSource

There is a very very long output in console. It's just a part of it. I've tried everything, it's still not working. I'm really exhausted.

Comment: There's not really enough to go one here, please add details on how you installed, what you've tried etc.

Comment: Right now it's working. I guess this have something to do with config, that I've downloaded from their site enable STOMP. It must be outdated or something.